# Recipient tab x/yposition mismatch

Tags: docusignapi

I can successfully add various tabs to a recipient of an draft envelope via the REST API. However, when I go to look at the target document via the manage tab of the website and I check the settings on the tab, the location values are completely different than what I entered via the REST API.

What is the difference? Why the difference? What exactly is the unit of measurement on the webpage as well as the API?

Answer (score 2):

If you're merely trying to determine the X/Y coordinate values to use in the REST API Create Envelope request such that tabs are displayed in expected/desired locations when the Envelope is viewed in DocuSign, you might try the following:

1) Using the DocuSign web console, create a (Draft) envelope and upload *the document(s) that you will be sending via the API*.  Also use the web interface to drag/drop tags into the proper locations on the document(s).  (Save as a Draft Envelope.) For example, here's a document where I've added two tags (SignHere and DateSigned):

[image: Create Envelope - doc tags]

2) Next, inspect the tab properties (X/Y coordinates) for that Draft Envelope ***via REST API request***: (https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?include_tabs=true&include_extended=true).  Here's an example response -- the highlighted values show X/Y coordinates for the tabs, ***according to the REST API***:

[image: REST API response]

3) Finally, to create an Envelope with tabs placed at the expected/desired locations when the Envelope is viewed in DocuSign, use a REST API "Create Envelope" request that contains the same documents used in Step #1 and specifies the X/Y coordinates that you received in Step #2 response (i.e., the X/Y coordinates according to the REST API).  For example, here's the "recipients" portion of the Create Envelope (JSON) request -- using X/Y coordinates that I received in Step #2 response.

```
"recipients": {
    "signers" : [{
        "email": "bobsemail@outlook.com",
        "name": "Bob Adamson",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [
            {
                "recipientId": "1",
                   "tabLabel": "Customer_Signature",
                   "documentId": "1",
                   "pageNumber": "1",
                   "xPosition": "99",
                   "yPosition": "424"
            }],
            "dateSignedTabs": [
            {
               "recipientId": "1",
               "tabLabel": "Customer_Date",
               "documentId": "1",
               "pageNumber": "1",
               "xPosition": "373",
               "yPosition": "456"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

If I then view (in DocuSign) the Envelope created by my "Create Envelope" request described in Step 3, I see that the tabs are placed exactly where I expect/desire them to be:

[image]

Obviously the process I've describe here is not ideal (it'd be much better if the X/Y coordinates set/retrieved via API matched Tab properties shown in the console), but perhaps it'll get you the end result you're shooting for.

Answer (score 1):

(Supplying this as an "Answer" instead of a "Comment" so that I can include code and images. I realize this doesn't necessarily answer your question -- but hopefully someone from DocuSign can comment on the scenarios I've outlined to provide clarification.)

Interesting.  Even if (for whatever reason) the unit of measurement for the X-Y coordinates that you supply via the API is different than the unit of measurement that the DocuSign web console uses for tab "Location" properties -- I'd expect the multiplying factor to be the same.  However, this does not appear to be the case.

For example -- if I submit an API request to create a Draft Envelope with a Signature tab that specifies **xPosition**=100 and **yPosition**=100 (as shown in the partial request JSON here):

```
"recipients": {
"signers" : [{
"email": "bobsEmail@outlook.com",
"name": "Bob Adamson",
"recipientId": "1",
"routingOrder": "1",
"tabs": {
       "signHereTabs": [
       {
           "recipientId": "1",
           "tabLabel": "Customer_Signature",
           "name": "KB_TEST_SIG",
           "documentId": "1",
           "pageNumber": "1",
           "xPosition": "100",
           "yPosition": "100"
       }]
   }
}]
```

and then open that Draft Envelope using the DocuSign web console and inspect the "Location" properties of the Signature tab, I get this:

[image: Tag Properties in web console]

Notice that even though the API request specified the same exact value (100) for both **xPosition** (definition: "indicates the horizontal offset of the tab on the page, in a coordinate space that has left top corner of the document as origin") and **yPosition** (definition: "indicates the vertical offset of the tab on the page, in a coordinate space that has left top corner of the document as origin"), the values that are shown in the console for **From left** and **From top** no longer match each other:

- From left: 208
- From top: 252

As another test, I tried doing things in reverse:

1. Create/Save a Draft Envelope via the web console, with a single Signature tab having Location properties **From left**=100 and **From top**=100.
2. Inspect the tab properties via API request:
   (https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?include_tabs=true&include_extended=true

The API response shows **xPosition**=48 and **yPosition**=27 (even though I set **From left**=100 and **From top**=100 when creating the draft envelope via the console).

The only logical conclusion that one can draw from all this is that the **xPosition** and **yPosition** coordinates specified via the API don't seem to map in any direct (and consistent) way to the **From left** and **From top** coordinates shown in Tag Properties within the console. Hopefully someone from DocuSign can confirm and/or clarify this behavior.

What's even more bizarre is that a Tag's X-Y coordinates returned via the SOAP API don't match the X-Y coordinates returned via the REST API (and of course, neither REST nor SOAP coordinates match what the console shows):

1. Create a Draft envelope with REST API.  Include a single SignHereTab with coordinates: **xPosition** = 100, **yPosition** = 100.
2. Inspect tag properties via the REST API (https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?include_tabs=true&include_extended=true). Tag coordinates are as expected:   **xPosition** = 100, **yPosition** = 100.
3. Inspect tag properties via the SOAP API (RequestStatusEx). Tag coordinates returned in the response:  **xPosition** = 208, **yPosition** = 208
4. Inspect tag properties via the Console (edit envelope >> view tag properties). Tag coordinates shown under "Location": **From left** = 208. **From top** = 252.

Comment: This is a great illustration. It makes me think that I can take your information and come up with a conversion factor(s) so I don't have to post a hundred draft envelopes trying to guess what x/ypositions I need to use in my code!

Comment: And a conversion factor probably would work except that you can give Sign Here tab and a Date Signed tab the same y-position via the REST API and get two different y-positions for the respective tabs via the web page (!)