# Signature/Initials/SignatureDate Tabs location issue

Tags: docusignapi

I have been having an issue with the location of signatures /initials for a long time now. Because a picture is worth a 1000 words, Im going to provide a screenshot as well as a json request.
In this test, I am trying to place a signature date and initials at different locations but with same Y axis coordinates.
As you can see in the json request, they both have "yPosition": "315"

However, as you can see in the image below, they have a total different Yaxis on the document. Do you have any idea  of what I am missing/doing wrong ?
[image]

```
{
  "status":"sent",
  "emailBlurb":"Test Email Body",
  "emailSubject": "Test Email Subject - EnvelopeDefFull",
  "documents": [{
      "name": "test1.pdf",
      "documentId":"1",
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Tab Coordinates Test Page.pdf",
        "documentBase64": ".....document Bytes....}],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "tabs": {
          "initialHereTabs": [
            {
              "scaleValue": "0.6",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "2",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "393",
              "yPosition": "315",
              "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }
          ],
          "dateSignedTabs": [
            {
              "bold": "True",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "2",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "460",
              "yPosition": "315"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": "Jane Smith",
        "email": "jane.smith@fakeemail.com",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "customFields": [
          "ROLE-14"
        ]
      }
    ],
   },
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this document",
  "notification": {
    "expirations": {
      "expireEnabled": "True",
      "expireAfter": "5"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, the **yPosition** aligns with the top edge of the tab. The top edge of the text tabs(For ex: DateSigned, FullName, Company, Title etc) seem to correctly align with the yPosition.

The signature tabs seems to have additional offset and it can differ based on the scaleValue used. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24998864/1219543) for the offset values.

**Tip**:You can use the Docusign Console to tag documents and get the accurate X&Y positions using the [getRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) call. You can then specify those coordinates in your API request to create new envelopes. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19845565/1219543)

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients?include_tabs=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the offset different when the scaleValue changes ?
Why such an offset ? and where is it documented ?
Im not sure I understand your tip, can you explain further ?

Comment: I am not sure why such an offset exists, but that seems to be the implementation. Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation related to the offsets.  Regarding the tip, I was suggesting that you use the Docusign sending [website](https://demo.docusign.net) and create a new envelope using the UI. You can place tabs on your document and save the envelope. You can then use the GetRecipients call to retrieve the X&Y positions for tabs. YOu can use these positions for subsequent create envelope calls through the API.

Comment: Oh, I get your tip now. I have been testing in Postman and got the same X&Y positions. I'm thinking this is a bug but can't be really sure