# DocuSign Api - TextTab size

Tags: docusignapi

I am having trouble with creating texttabs via the docusign REST API.
The creation succeed, but when I open the DocuSign page to sign the document, the created texttabs have not the defined size.
Interestingly the created notetabs with the same size work properly.
I compare the texttab with a Textbox with the size 100 px * 100 px.

How can I fix this issue?

```
    "textTabs": [
        {
            "height": 100,
            "name": "Test1",
            "width": 100,
            "disableAutoSize": "true",
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "291",
            "yPosition": "244"
        }
    ]
```

[image: texttab in the textbox compare to a word textbox]

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Text%20Tab.htm check width

Comment: @SilentTremor Thanks, I follow that guide. But the yellow DocuSign box doesn't fill out the 100px *100px frame.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign adds some additional offsets based on the Tab Type that is being used.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056330/1219543) for more information.

**Troubleshooting Tip:** 
I suggest, you use the [DocuSign Web](https://demo.docusign.net) Sending UI to tag your documents and use the [lisEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) to retrieve the Tab positions. You can then use the Tab positions for your subsequent API calls.

Comment: The offset is not a problem for me. As I wrote I have problems with the size. I want that the app users define the size of the tabs. I tried to adjust the tabs in the Web Sending UI for different sizes and compared it and tried to find a possible multiplicator or a similarity, but without result.